# How is crossfilter() affecting this measure calculation in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables: Date and Sales

Date:

Values in Date column is unique, values in “related date in 2019” is not unique.

Sample data:

| Date | related date in 2019 |
| --- | --- |
| 2-4-2023 | 2-9-2019 |
| 2-5-2023 | 2-10-2019 |
| 2-6-2023 | 2-11-2019 |
| 2-7-2023 | 2-12-2019 |
| 2-8-2023 | 2-13-2019 |
| 2-9-2023 | 2-14-2019 |
| 2-10-2023 | 2-15-2019 |

Sales sample data:

| date | store | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/11/2019 | A | 4 |
| 2/14/2019 | A | 7 |
| 2/11/2019 | B | 2 |
| 2/14/2019 | B | 6 |
| 2/11/2019 | C | 7 |
| 2/14/2019 | C | 3 |

There are 2 relationships defined between Date and Sales. One is one to many between 'Date'[Date] and Sales[date]; the other is many to many between ‘Date’[related date in 2019] and Sales[date]

WTD sales 2019 for 2/9/2023 is calculated as:

For 2/9/2023, WTD dates are 2/6/2023 - 2/9/2023. The corresponding dates in 2019 for these dates based on ‘Date’[related date in 2019] are 2/11/2019 to 2/14/2019. As a result, WTD sales 2019 for 2/9/2023 is calculated as total sales for 2/11/2019 to 2/14/2019.

I have following measure:

```
Sales WTD 2019 =
VAR firstDayofWeek =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] ) - WEEKDAY ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] ), 2 ) + 1
VAR CurrentDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[sales] ),
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'Date'[Date], firstDayofWeek, currentdate ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Date'[related date in 2019], Sales[date] ) 
        //, CROSSFILTER( 'Date'[Date] , Sales[date] , None )
    )
```

When `CROSSFILTER( 'Date'[Date] , Sales[date] , None )` is NOT used, WTD sales 2019 for 2/9/2023 is 32 which is incorrect.

When `CROSSFILTER( 'Date'[Date] , Sales[date] , None )` is used, WTD sales 2019 for 2/9/2023 is 29 which is correct.

My questions are:

Why is `CROSSFILTER` needed in the measure? Shouldn’t the other relationship be deactivated when `USERELATIONSHIP` is in place?
When `CROSSFILTER` is not used, how is the value of 32 calculated?

Please find pbix here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fls716yz01FgIqmQ6JVHNmDBbuy8R07k/view?usp=drive_link

Thanks.

Comment: Which (if any) of your two relationships is active?

Comment: default is between 'Date'[Date] and Sales[date]

Comment: I can confirm in the case with 2x 1:n it works without  requiring the additional crossfilter to deactivate one relationship. I am not at a PC, so cannot open your pbix. For m:n with a bridge table to work, there is also one bi-directional relationship with the bridge table. Could it be related to such a bi-directional relationship? (On the hand, in your case it’s not activate as default)

Comment: There are 2 relationships defined between Date and Sales. One is one to many between 'Date'[Date] and Sales[date] which is active by default; the other is many to many between ‘Date’[related date in 2019] and Sales[date] which is used in the measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was a really interesting question!

### How is `2023-02-09` calculated when `CROSSFILTER` is NOT applied?

I believe the calculation is not as you expect it to be, because while you are using `USERELATIONSHIP` to transplant the active relationship,  you are also using the primary/active relationship column in the DAX expression to establish the filter context. By doing this, I believe you are persisting the use of the **active** relationship. In other words, `USERELATIONSHIP` will **not** be able transplant the active relationship as the calculation is set up. This behavior is alluded to in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> In USERELATIONSHIP, the status of a relationship is not important; that is, whether the relationship is active or not does not affect the usage of the function. Even if the relationship is inactive, it will be used and overrides any other active relationships that might be present in the model **but not mentioned in the function arguments**.

Hence, for your `2023-02-09` you are simply summing the sales amount over the period `2023-02-06` to `2023-02-09`, which turns out to be 32.

### How is `2023-02-09` calculated when `CROSSFILTER` is applied?

When you explicitly turn off the primary relationship, the filter context becomes what you expect, since you are removing the option of using the primary relationship altogether, so to speak.

### Are there other ways to solve this?

If you are not comfortable with using both `CROSSFILTER` and `USERELATIONSHIP` in the same expression (this can be explained in a comment, obviously, but may still be difficult to grasp?), you can opt for something like this instead, where we first calculate the appropriate 2019 dates using `VALUES`, and use `TREATAS` to propagate the filter context to sales:

```
Sales WTD 2019 =
VAR _current_date =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR _first_day_of_week =
    _current_date - WEEKDAY ( _current_date, 2 ) + 1
VAR _dates =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Date'[related date in 2019] ),
        DATESBETWEEN ( 'Date'[Date], _first_day_of_week, _current_date )
    )
VAR _out =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[sales] ),
        ALL ( Sales ),
        TREATAS ( _dates, Sales[sales_date] )
    )
RETURN
    _out
```

Comment: sorry if I misunderstand. Rgd. the first part of the sentence which you highlighted/emphasized the last part - my understanding is that with USERELATIONSHIP you can change/choose/overidethe relationship regardless what is defined in the model. As mentioned in my comment, it works with 1:n relationships without requiring CROSSFILTER (e.g. as also described here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-userelationship-in-dax/)

Comment: When I had a look at the pbix I changed the default active relationship to the m:n relation. As stated in my answer, in that case it works without CROSSFILTER (applying USERELATIONSHIP for the 1:n instead). Would be interesting if you can reproduce this as well. Cheers!

Comment: If you change the active relationship to be between `sales[date]` and `date[related date in 2019]` then obviously it works without needing to apply `CROSSFILTER`, since you are not transplanting the active filter. There is no required interaction between `sales[date]` and `date[date]`.

Comment: Your link has zero relevance to this effect. OP is trying to replace an active relationship, but uses the active relationship to establish the filtering context (e.g. date[Date] in the calculate expression) which prevents the transplant altogether.

Comment: Tack for your explanation. Sorry, if I was not clear: When I changed  the active relationship in the model to m:n, I did not change the DATESBETWEEN reference with Date[Date]. Obviously, for the m:n neither USERELATIONSHIP nor CROSSFILTER is needed. But then, when I changed the relationship to 1:n with USERELATIONSHIP it works without any CROSSFILTER.

Comment: I'm still not clear why USERELATIONSHIP does not deactivate the other relationship. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Jeff I did one more thing and updated my original answer from yesterday accordingly. Maybe you already did the same testing too. You could call it a bug, l guess. On the other hand, there is also areminder/warning in PowerBI when using m:n relations.

Comment: It does not deactivate the relationship because your expression uses a column that is part of the active relationship column in `Date`. I do agree this seems like "buggish" behavior, since it is somewhat unexpected based on the code you provide.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download your pbix:

So, if `CROSSFILTER` is not used, it seems the **active** relationship remains the default **1:n** between **Date[Date]** and **Sales[date]**

In that case, for the **2/9/2023**, you will get the **17+15 = 32** from that week (2/6 and 2/9)

Interestingly, if you change the default **active** relationship to the **m:n** with bi-directions between **Date[related date in 2019]** and **Sales[date]**, the `USERELATIONSHIP` works without `CROSSFILTER`, i.e., applying USERELATIONSHIP to switch to the deactivated 1:n works without CROSSFILTER

**Edit:**

I also noticed a potential issue with your measure with the week around **1/1/2023** and **12/31/2022**. There is a “jump” from **1/6/2019** to **1/4/2020** in the **[related date in 2019]**. So the calculation in this case sums up values with a year gap.

Alternatively, if applicable, might be easier just to **calculate the offset to 2019** in your measure instead of using the second column and avoiding the second relationship with m:n

**Edit 2 (6/6):**

I just did one more thing: I added another column **Date[related date in 2019 distinct]** with distinct dates and defined a third, **deactivated 1:n relation** to **Sales[date]**

In that case the measure works just fine too, i.e., having the default, **active 1:n** between **Date[Date]** and **Sales[date]**, using `USERELATIONSHIP` to switch to the **1:n** relation between **Date[related date in 2019 distinct]** and **Sales[date]** produces the expected result without the presence of `CROSSFILTER`

#### Brief Summary

- in your setup, `USERELATIONSHIP` of the **m:n connection** does not work without additional `CROSSFILTER` and the active 1:n connection prevails
- on the other hand, using `USERELATIONSHIP` to switch to another **1:n connection** works as expected (w/o the need of `CROSSFILTER`)

#### Workaround

- change your model setup to have the m:n connection active and to switch to the 1:n with `USERELATIONSHIP` (w/o `CROSSFILTER`) instead
- use a formula to calculate the date offset instead of the second date column avoiding m:n (my personal preference)
- proposal from @Marcus: use virtual table and `TREATAS`